# Multiple storyboards not loading localization

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization, uistoryboard

I have an application that has a few different Storyboards, and is using Base Internationalization for localizing into French. The Main.storyboard that has its .strings file with translations loads with French just fine. However, when I instantiate a new storyboard, and present it, it remains in English. I was simply doing this to load the storyboard before:

```
UIStoryboard *upcomingStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
/// Code to present initial view controller.
```

This just loads the English storyboard. I then tried following the instructions [from this site](http://arssubtilior.blog.com/2013/04/25/instantiating-a-localized-storyboard/), which changed my code to:

```
NSString *language   = @"Base";
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *preferred  = [[mainBundle preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([[mainBundle localizations] containsObject:preferred]) {
    language = preferred;
}
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[mainBundle pathForResource:language
                                                                 ofType:@"lproj"]];
UIStoryboard *upcomingStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:bundle];
```

All this did was cause the app to crash when loading the storyboard, which is probably because there no actual storyboard file in the `fr.lproj`, just a `.strings` file. Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: Why can't you use `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`? The storyboard I use in my app isn't the main storyboard and it is localized with no issues. If you pass `nil` into the bundle argument then it will not localise anything. That's why the bundle argument is there.

Comment: I've also tried that with no luck. You're using base internationalization with a .strings file for the storyboards?

Comment: You passed the main bundle in? i.e. not just nil.

Comment: Yes, I've tried `[NSBundle mainBundle]`

Comment: Yes, I'm using base internationalisation and .strings files for storyboard. I even have a method similar to yours where I pass the storyborad name in because I use two storyboards.

Comment: I've put an answer just in case you want to copy the code but it all works with my project.

Comment: If I create a new project, it works the way you describe. But my current project does not. Looks like I have some more fun ahead of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using multiple storyboards in my localised app. None of them are set as the "Main Interface" file. They are all loaded in code depending on where the user needs to be in the app.

Essentially I have a login storyboard that walks the user through logging in and an "app" storyboard for the content of the app.

The project uses base internationalisation (with English as the development language) and strings files for all the translations (nibs, storyboards and code).

They are loaded through a method like this...

```
- (void)showStoryboardWithName:(NSString *)storyboardName transition:(UIViewAnimationOptions)transition
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self showViewController:controller withTransition:transition];
}
```

I have 15ish languages localised in the app and they all work with this.

Comment: Not sure what finally did the trick. I had uninstalled several times, and had no luck. I finally dug out an old iPod touch and installed it, and everything worked as expected. Then I uninstalled again from my phone, and it worked there. Thanks for confirming that it should have worked that easily, and I was the crazy one :)